# Android, вызов onTouchListener только внутри view

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

Имеется кнопка, с прикрепленным `onTouchListener`. Если я нажимаю кнопку и двигаю палец за границы кнопки, то `onTouchListener` всё равно вызывается. Как можно поменять это поведение, чтобы обработчик не вызывался за пределами View, к которому он прикреплен?

Сделал скриншот проблемы, которую пытаюсь решить. Когда я нажимаю палецем и двигаю им к нижней части экрана, то после определенной черты при опускании второго пальца координаты странным образом "прыгают", а мне нужна точная обработка касания в зеленых границах, без мультитачей и выхода за зеленые границы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: гляньте ответ = )

Comment: Да я уже давно решение нашел через костыли. Вопрос то 2016, но галочку поставлю, ладно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо переопределить `onTouchEvent` для корневого `View` следующим образом (тем самым вы будете игнорировать мультитач в пределах этого `View`):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1)
        //если определили второе и более касание, игнорируем его
        return true;
    else
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```